# InApp message appears unexpectedly when opening the app

Tags: sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush-android, salesforce-sdk-android

So, we have implemented delayed displaying of InApp messages. It is done pretty much the way it is shown in documentation, inside Application class `onCreate()`:

```
private suspend fun initSalesforce() {

    val moduleConfig = SFMCSdkModuleConfig.build {
        pushModuleConfig = MarketingCloudConfig.builder().apply {
            setApplicationId(configuration.applicationId)
            setAccessToken(configuration.accessToken)
            setMarketingCloudServerUrl(configuration.marketingCloudServerUrl)
            setMid(configuration.mid)
            setDelayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet(true)
            setNotificationCustomizationOptions(
                NotificationCustomizationOptions.create(
                    R.drawable.ic_notification,
                    SalesforceNotificationLaunchIntentProvider(),
                    SalesforceNotificationChannelIdProvider()
                )
            )
            setUrlHandler(SalesforceDeeplinkUrlHandler())
            setAnalyticsEnabled(true)
            fcmToken?.let { setSenderId(it) }
        }.build(applicationContext)
    }

    SFMCSdk.configure(
        this@App as Application,
        moduleConfig
    ) { initStatus ->
        if (initStatus.status == FAILURE) return@configure

        SFMCSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
            sdk.mp {
                it.inAppMessageManager.apply {
                    setTypeface(
                        ResourcesCompat.getFont(
                            applicationContext,
                            R.font.our_custom_font
                        )
                    )
                    setInAppMessageListener(
                        InAppMessagesEventListener { message ->
                            shouldShowSalesforceMessage(message)
                        }
                    )
                }
            }

            val profileAttributes = mapOf<String, String?>(
                "appLanguage" to appLanguage,
                "appVersion" to appVersion
            )
            sdk.identity.apply {
                salesforceUserId?.let {
                    setProfileId(salesforceUserId)
                }
                setProfileAttributes(profileAttributes)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`shouldShowSalesforceMessage()` returns false by default unless specific scenario.

Issue itself: From time to time InApp appears when app just opened, even if `shouldShowSalesforceMessage()` is hardcoded to return false. I did an investigation, put logs and here is what is happening.

Sometimes, SDK receives InApps **immidiately after** SDK is being initialized - **before** setting up the InAppMessageListener. So it leads to a situation that InApp is being displayed when it shouldnt.
it is not happening every time but it happens from time to time, and for our particular app it is unacceptable. Unfortunately, I have not found any solution yet to prevent such a case.

I would highly, highly appreciate any help for fixing this issue.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have no experienced this, and I apologize, but I don't recall having a support case related to this sent to my team.

Something you can try:

Put your `requestSdk` call outside of the initialization callback. The requests for the SDK are executed as soon as the SDK becomes available and that can (does) happen before the initialization status is reported.